# Apache: How to specify caching for .js and .css files?

Tags: php, apache, caching

I understand that during website development, caching can be disabled entirely at the start of any page using PHP using the directive

```
if (getenv("DEVELOP"))
    header("Cache-Control: no-store");
```

But for production use, caching is desired for all files that do not often change.

My understanding is that Apache webservers cache HTML files (or the HTML produced by PHP files) by default, but not style or JavaScript files.

I further understand that caching for non-HTML files can be specified either in the config file or in an .htaccess file using the directive "Header set Cache-Control". What are some typical ways to do this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking

Comment: I'd like Apache to cache style and JavaScript files like it already caches html files. Can you specify what is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

Apache doesn't cache PHP, the code is executed each time. However the code is compiled into zend vm bytecode provided PHP is loaded into apache as a module and the bytecode is stored until the underlying php file is changed. The HTTP header is for the web browsers so they don't make repeated requests to your server.

If you want to cache dynamic pages on your server using only apache and php you will have to do it yourself. You can do it with php in numerous ways. You can modify existing php files [using php's output control funcitons](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.outcontrol.php) and write the output to a file which would then be linked from your site. Then you will need to set up a cron, supervisor or systemd job to periodically run the php file(s).

Alternatively some frameworks like laravel will do some caching for you if you configure it to. A very popular solution nowadays is to combine apache with nginx for caching purposes.